# Which element should I choose for this Tampermonkey script? Or can it wait to the end of loading of everything?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I assembled this simple code to click the first download link of several download links.
The problem is that I'll have to wait for download links to show up(there's some transforming process). I did a test, they show up much later than Load or `DOMContentLoaded`. (BTW,is there any way to describe the real end of loading of EVERYTHING like this situation?)

Here's an example link:
    https://www.saveoffline.com/#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEROU2XtPR8

Anyway, first off I assembled a code that waits 30 seconds then click the link for me, it works, I got the correct target link!
But internet connection speed varies,30 sec is not perfect, so now I want a code to click that download link automatically when links show up. Here's the code:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        saveoffline click first format
// @include     https://www.saveoffline.com/*
// @grant       none

var x = 0
function waitforgrab() {
    // 1200 = 10min/500ms of waiting
    if(x>1200) stopthere();//use a wrong function to stop this js.
    if(document.getElementById("output")===null) {//I have to pick the correct element to describe download links showing up.
        x = x+1
        setTimeout(waitforgrab(), 500)
    }
}
waitforgrab();
// the above lines : wait until download links show up.

// the following line: click first link. This line proves correct.
document.getElementById("media-formats").firstElementChild.click();
```

The test result:

> ERROR: Execution of script 'saveoffline click first format' failed! Cannot read property 'click' of null...

So, I chose the wrong element? - although this element is not null, it does not mean download links show up? But I tried 4 or 5 elements, just not right.

Please help me find this "correct" element. Or, maybe how to describe the real end of load of EVERYTHING, then I could just simply click the target download link.

Comment: `setTimeout(waitforgrab(), 500)` does not make sense. `waitforgrab` doesn’t return a function, so it should be `setTimeout(waitforgrab, 500)`.

Comment: What does the `#output` element have to do with the `#media-formats` element? You don't appear to be trying to do anything with the `#output` element, why are you checking it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for help.That's because target link is a child of something, don't know how to decribe it, so I try to use the block that includes all links, also this block is not there at early stage of loading.

Comment: Why not just test for the existence of `#media-formats`, or something like `#media-formats > div:first-child`, instead of `#output`? That would seem to be more logical, given what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @CertainPerformance Just now I tried with "document.getElementById("media-formats").firstElementChild===null", still getting "Cannot read property 'click' of null".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't reinvent the wheel.  As you discovered, trying to guesstimate loading delay, on the web, is a very brittle approach.
   Use something like `waitForKeyElements` or `MutationObserver`.
2. `document.getElementById("media-formats")` fires immediately, NOT after the `setTimeout`s.
3. There are several other issues with that code, replace it with something like what's shown below.
4. On an AJAX-driven page, there is seldom a way to "describe the real end of loading of everything". And if there is, it is highly page specific -- so not something to rely on.

Anyway, since you linked the target page, the correct selector is shown in this **complete working Tampermonkey script:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Saveoffline, click the first download format
// @match    https://www.saveoffline.com/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */

waitForKeyElements ("#media-formats > a > .formatButton", clickNode, true);

function clickNode (jNode) {
    //- The buttons are loaded in reverse order, so ensure we have the first child.
    var frstNode   = jNode.parent ().siblings ().first ().children (".formatButton");
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    frstNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I found this jquery method will click the last link in those download links, instead, so I replaced clickNode function's content with "document.getElementById("media-formats").firstElementChild.click();" and it works. But how should I fix it in jquery way?

Comment: See the updated answer.  However, if your current method works, it is also acceptable.  jQuery is great, but no need to use it just for the sake of using it . ([¡Blasphemy!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif))